# Pandas_datareader and Google Colab. Should it work?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Going through a finance tutorial.  The tutorial uses import pandas_datareader to read in stock data from Yahoo.

Running this on my local computer works.  But it does not work through Google Colab.  Is this a limitation of Jupyter notebooks?

Comment: Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe? Presently, there's not enough detail in the question to understand the problem that you are observing.

Comment: Here is a sample of the code from the finance tutorial.

Comment: import datetime

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from pandas_datareader import data, wb

GE = data.DataReader(name='GE', data_source='yahoo',start='2021-8-1')
print("Stock: DE")
print(DE)